# Bootstrap mega menu take style from chrome dev mode

Tags: html, css, megamenu

I'm trying to add a mega menu to my website. I found one that is working and that I like. But I have a problem with the styling I can't seem to solve.

Here is how the dropdown menu looks like:

[image]

Not the checkbox in Chrome Dev mode: `.dropdown, .dropup { position: relative; }`
Now, when I untick this checkbox, I get the result I want, namely this:

[image]

Now my question is, how can I include this in my css code for it to be displayed the way I want it to be?

Here is the code for my menu:

```
    <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light rounded">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 4 Mega Menu</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbars" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown megamenu-li">
       <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Mega Menu 1</a>
       <div class="dropdown-menu megamenu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
          <h5>Links</h5>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
          <h5>More Links</h5>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
          <h5>Paragraph</h5>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus in veritatis, facilis eligendi sunt, culpa autem harum porro earum.</p>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
          <h5>Image</h5>
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/250x150/?sig=4" alt="..." style="width: 100%;">
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown megamenu-li">
       <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="dropdown02" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Mega Menu 2</a>
       <div class="dropdown-menu megamenu" aria-labelledby="dropdown02">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <h5>Image Slider</h5>
          <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
           <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
             <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://source.unsplash.com/250x150/?sig=1" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
             <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://source.unsplash.com/250x150/?sig=2" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
             <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://source.unsplash.com/250x150/?sig=3" alt="...">
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
          <h5>Links</h5>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-5">
          <h5>Paragraph</h5>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam impedit itaque minus distinctio possimus reiciendis et repellat. Voluptate, temporibus veniam et praesentium alias, maxime repudiandae aliquid, natus omnis animi iste!</p>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

and here is the css:

```
.megamenu-li {
    position: static;
}

.megamenu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

I already tried to include what was displayed on the dev mode in Google Chrome, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: You can add the following to your css `.dropdown, .dropup { position: static !important;}` Only add the !important if your style is being overwritten (which i doubt will happen)

Comment: Great, it's working! Thank you so much Nico! I didn't consider the possibility of using the "!important! tag!

Comment: You're welcome, glad i could help!